# Convert request body to datatable or dataset in C#

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, dataset

I am making a azure function that takes a request body. with the following format.

"10","Name","112","50012","Activity","08/02/2021","3:20","3:10",""
"10","Name","","","Break","08/02/2021"," - ","0:11","Break"
"10","Name","112","50012","Activity","08/02/2021","2:09","2:09",""

The first pair of strings is the worker ID, second is the name, 3rd is the id of the customer, 4th is the activity id, 5th is the activity, 6th is the date, 7th is the raw amount of hours worked, 8th is calculated amount of hours worked and last indicates if it was a break.

Short there is 9 sets of string on each line and there is no telling how many lines there are. Now i want to convert this to a datatable and then to a dataset. So far i have only been able to read the body like this.

```
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
        {
            var ResponseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DataTables aren't particularly hard to create- you make a new one - `var dt = new DataTable()`, you repeatedly do `dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(T))` where T is like `string`, `int` etc - 9 times in your case, then you repeatedly do `dt.Rows.Add(nine,items,of,data,from,your,csv,go,here)`with your data rows. Have a go at it, so we don't feel quite so much like you're saying "write my program for me"

Comment: Look up CSV reader. I'm also curious why you want to use a DataTable

Comment: @Flydog57 I want to convert the datatable to a XML Workbook

Comment: @CaiusJard I understand how that works but its is a whole set of strings and i don't know how to loop over the rows. I do know how to add the rows and columns

Comment: So data is posted to your function as it is in your question. Just lines of CSV text. Then just wrap it in a `StreamReader` and use `ReadLineAsync` until there is nothing left to read. You should really look up `CSVHelper` nuget package.

Comment: I give up, what's an _XML Workbook_? Did you look up CSV Reader? Your data is in a pretty standard format, known as _Comma Separated Value_ (or CSV) format. A CSV Reader will read it into a collection of objects. If you do it right, it will translate "112" an an integer and "08/02/2021" as a DateTime. The quotes in you input don't delimit strings, the delimiter entities in the input stream

Comment: *loop over the rows* - reader.ReadToEnd makes that hard work. Consider reader.ReadLine instead

Comment: @Andy reader is already a StreamReader, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting you a sample approach and you can take this as reference for solving your actual problem.

So you have to read the data line by line and split the data.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] columns = [];//column names as you have mentioned in your data there are no columns 
foreach (string column in columns)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(column);
}
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
{
    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        string[] rows = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = rows[i];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Assumption: I’m assuming that you have no comma in between values

Comment: What if the data is `"hello", "how", "are", "you, vivek?"`